# Cannot build with Gradle

Tags: gradle

I'm having issues building with gradle. It throws this exception for any project I try to build:

```
2022-10-26T12:16:04.514+0200 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] 
2022-10-26T12:16:04.515+0200 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
2022-10-26T12:16:04.515+0200 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] 
2022-10-26T12:16:04.515+0200 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] * What went wrong:
2022-10-26T12:16:04.515+0200 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] A problem occurred configuring root project 'LanguageImplementationPatterns'.
2022-10-26T12:16:04.515+0200 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] > Could not load compiled classes for build file '/home/svukadin/northbridge/tmp/LanguageImplementationPatterns/build.gradle' from cache.
2022-10-26T12:16:04.515+0200 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]
```

It does not matter which project I try it's the same. It suggests to use the --scan feature so I do and then I get this strange thing:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Auto-applied by using --scan

* What went wrong:
An exception occurred applying plugin request [id: 'com.gradle.enterprise', version: '3.4.1', artifact: 'com.gradle:gradle-enterprise-gradle-plugin:3.4.1']
> Could not find implementation class 'com.gradle.enterprise.gradleplugin.GradleEnterprisePlugin' for plugin 'com.gradle.enterprise' specified in jar:file:/home/svukadin/.gradle/caches/jars-8/8d335fae97ae4c2a6592f56bf32b7baa/gradle-enterprise-gradle-plugin-3.4.1.jar!/META-INF/gradle-plugins/com.gradle.enterprise.properties.
```

I try to unzip the mentioned jar manualy and I get a lot of bad CRC errors:

```
  inflating: META-INF/MANIFEST.MF    
  inflating: com.gradle.scan.plugin.internal.meta.buildAgentVersion.txt  
  inflating: META-INF/NOTICE.txt      bad CRC 41e1d32b  (should be 7e9f11ac)
  inflating: META-INF/licenses/jackson-core-2.11.0/NOTICE.txt   bad CRC b086255b  (should be 3f58cc88)
  inflating: META-INF/licenses/jackson-databind-2.11.0/LICENSE.txt  
...
```

Tried clearing all caches, tried with no deamon, tried changing gradle wrapper version...

Don't know what's the issue... It seems it downloads malformed JAR archives from my perspective.

Java and Gradle versions:

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_342"
-----------
------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 6.6.1
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2020-08-25 16:29:12 UTC
Revision:     f2d1fb54a951d8b11d25748e4711bec8d128d7e3

Kotlin:       1.3.72
Groovy:       2.5.12
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.8 compiled on May 10 2020
JVM:          1.8.0_342 (Private Build 25.342-b07)
OS:           Linux 5.4.0-131-generic amd64
```

Contents of build.gradle

```groovy
plugins {
    id 'idea'
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'antlr'

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
    workingDir = '.'
}

dependencies {
    // Use JUnit test framework
    testCompile("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.5.1")
    testCompile("org.hamcrest:hamcrest-all:1.3")
    testRuntimeOnly("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.5.1")

    // ANTLR
    antlr "org.antlr:antlr:3.5.2" // use ANTLR version 3
    compile 'org.antlr:antlr-runtime:3.5.2'
    testCompile 'org.antlr:antlr-runtime:3.5.2'
}
```

Comment: What commands are you running? What versions of Gradle and Java are you using?

Comment: Java: openjdk version "1.8.0_342" Gradle is from the wrapper: `$ ./gradlew --version` gives: 
`------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 6.6.1
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2020-08-25 16:29:12 UTC
Revision:     f2d1fb54a951d8b11d25748e4711bec8d128d7e3

Kotlin:       1.3.72
Groovy:       2.5.12
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.8 compiled on May 10 2020
JVM:          1.8.0_342 (Private Build 25.342-b07)
OS:           Linux 5.4.0-131-generic amd64
`

Comment: if you update your question to include this information then it's easier to read :)

Comment: How have you defined the repositories? https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html#sec:plugin-vs-build-repos Update your question to include the contents of `build.gradle(.kts)` and `settings.gradle(.kts)`